# Why I got an error browsing apkcure site by Firefox?

Tags: security, firefox, connection, vpn

Question: **What is wrong with My Firefox**?
I have connected to router G-97RG6W by wire, tariff is up to 500 MB/sec.

I am using Firefox. PC Desktop, OS Windows 7 Unlimited.

The connection speed practically as declared.

As a sample i tried to connect to site https://apkpure.com/ru/apk-signature-verification

and often I got a message:

**Secure Connection Failed
An error occurred during a connection to apkpure.com. PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR
Error code: PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.**

Really I am note sure the fault is on site owners, because I have no right to suppose such a company as apkpure may do any mistake...

The problem disappears when the VPN is on.

Sometimes, mostly after first PC turned on  the connection successful without VPN.

This case the connection's speed great, with VPN speed  essentially lower.

One may see the protocol is **https**.

**Question**: What was really happened? Is there any fault from my side? What I can do for solving this problem?.

I suppose the problem is created by my VPN, I am using ITop VPN. May be this is their desire to force me to use their product? Why they insisting "my Internet connection is slow"? "I should install their upgrade, and so on".

May be just kill this  VPN?

Cordially,

Radmir

I wrote what I know.

Answer (score 0):

My answer:

I made the next test for this site:

I stopped ITOP VPN, installed on my Windows 7 PC PlanetVPN. The last additionally have installed some application for better working their VPN. I stopped PlanetVPN and tried to connect to site mentioned. Success! As a result I removed ITop VPN and I think not for nothing, the connection speed through this VPN less then 1 MB/sec, thus gives the lost from 500 MB/sec to nothing is unacceseptable. Don't think PlanetVPN is significantly better, which converts my 500 MB/sec into17 MB/sec, this is a little greater but not match... But if really is any good solution for this problem then where it? May be just use Proxy or ask  Elon Musk for help?
Truly Yours,
Radmir.